# iOS Firestore App runs on Simulator but not on phone

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

I am developing an App that uses Firestore. The app runs fine on the Xcode simulator, but crashes when I try to run it on my phone. I get the following error message:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'FIRIllegalStateException', reason: 'Failed to get FirebaseApp
>   instance. Please call FirebaseApp.configure() before using Firestore'

I do call FirebaseApp.configure() in the didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        FirebaseApp.configure()
        return true
    }
```

I don't understand why it would run in the simulator and not on my phone. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: can you add your podfile code related to install firebase

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered, on a Japanese code forum, what to do. I added the following code to the AppDelegate.swift file:

```
var window: UIWindow?

override init() { //初期化メソッドを追記
        FirebaseApp.configure()
}
```

The app now runs both in the simulator and on my iPhone.

Answer (score 0):

Check your podfile for how you add the firebase cocoapods, It should be like this,

```
  pod 'FirebaseCore'
  pod 'Firebase/Messaging'
```

If your podfile different ,please remove old firebase related pods,insert this and install.